# Remove all pending connections from the listener Queue

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am working on a console server app that listens on a port for a incoming connections. Every time I restart the console app, it has a pending connection queue which is causing the console server app to crash.

Is there a way to remove all pending connections in the queue before accepting new connections ?

Comment: this answer might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231789/cancel-blocking-accepttcpclient-call/12489289#12489289

Comment: Causes it to crash how? The pending connection queue does not survive the closing of the listening socket. Post your problem, not your diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server app needs to set [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) socket [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx):

```
server_socket.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
    SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true );
```

to be able to bind the listening port after restart.