# Ftp Client, Timeout error only solved when service is restarted

Tags: c#, service, ftp

I have an very unusual error. We have a service running that periodically checks and downloads files from a remote server. The problem is, for this one client, we sometimes get these timeout errors none stop that we can only resolve by restarting the service.

The Service creates a class called FileTransfer then on error completely disposes the classes before trying again 2 additional times. After than 15 minutes it runs again only to the same result, an error after 3 attempts. When we restart the service it works fine again. I also confirmed that everything is getting disposed correctly.

thanks in advance guys, ANY ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: can you post the code in regards to how you are initializing the Class, consuming it as well as disposing it.. you could be getting some null reference errors that are not being handled properly in regards to how what you are doing if you have any exception handling or not.. kind of hard to answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for responding! i found the answer to this questions here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044415/how-can-i-restart-communication-with-an-ftp-server-that-sends-back-reset-packets