# AcceptTcpClient Blocking the rest of the code

Tags: c#, tcpclient

*Hi, I have this code here*

```
if (Main && List && Admin)
{
Console.WriteLine("[SERVER]" + "Waiting to connect");
TcpClient ClientList = ListServer.AcceptTcpClient();
if (ClientList.Connected)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine(ListMessage + "CONECTED !");
}
NextCode();
      }
  }

 private void NextCode()
{
//CODE
}
```

*When you come to the line: `TcpClient ClientList = ListServer.AcceptTcpClient();`. The program waits for a connection. How do I stop waiting in the background and further lines of code to perform?*

Comment: I think it is not good to use methods such as "NextCode" since this reminds me of "spaghetti code."  To make a program stop waiting for a particular line, you can use async methods in .NET.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231789/cancel-blocking-accepttcpclient-call

Comment: @Phil_12d3 Not at all

Comment: If not a duplicate, the solution is most certainly contained there.

Answer (score 3):

AcceptTcpClient is a blocking call.  You will either need to move your connection listening work in to a separate thread, or use Asyc method calls to accept connections without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

use a Background Worker:

```
//define this outside
TcpClient ClientList;

//....
    if (Main && List && Admin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[SERVER]" + "Waiting to connect");
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        NextCode();
    }

}

private void NextCode()
{
    //CODE
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ClientList = ListServer.AcceptTcpClient();
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ClientList.Connected)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(ListMessage + "CONECTED !");
    }
}
```