# Cancel Token within Blocking Task under the hood

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have two buttons that start and stop a `TcpListener`.

```
private void buttonStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    _listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 5000);
    cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;
    var taskListener = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        (t) => Listener(token),token,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void Listener(CancellationToken token)
{
    _listener.Start();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        TcpClient c;
        try
        {
            c = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Accept(c))
            .ContinueWith(ant => richTextBoxMessage.AppendText(ant.Result), _uiScheduler);
    }
}

private void buttonStopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancelSource.Cancel();
    _listener.Stop();
    richTextBoxMessage.AppendText("Server shutdown");
}
```

`Accept` is some method that reads from the TcpClient. My question is, before I stop the server by clicking the button, my server is blocked at

```
try {c = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();}
```

So how does clicking the cancel button kill the `taskListener`? Without having a `ManualResetEvent` or `ManualResetEventSlim`? I am able to toggle between server shutdown and server restart. What's going on under the hood? I'm targeting `.NET 4.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how does clicking the cancel button kill the taskListener?

When you call [`TcpListener.Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) in your cancel event handler, internally it will close the underlying `Socket`, and raise a `SocketException`. This exception is swallowed by your `catch` all block, which simply breaks the loop.

The documentation state this explicitly (emphasis mine):

> Stop closes the listener. Any unaccepted connection requests in the
>   queue will be lost. **Remote hosts waiting for a connection to be
>   accepted will throw a SocketException.** You are responsible for closing
>   your accepted connections separately.

You can see this by printing out the exception in the `catch` block:

```
TcpClient c;
try
{
    c = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Socket exception was raised: {0}", e);
    if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted)
        Debug.WriteLine("Blocking listen was interrupted");
}
```

Comment: Gotcha - so the cancellation token isn't really doing anything? What's a better practice? Killing it this way or using the cancellation token?

Comment: The problem is there is no overload of `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient` that takes a cancellation token, so you're forced to call `Stop` and catch the exception. If you can use the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package for .NET 4.0, I'd go with [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856169/1870803).